# Gulp and Browserify, dependency management with Node.js require();. Put jQuery on top?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, gulp, browserify

I don't think this question is a duplicate, because jquery doesn't need to be shimmed anymore. I downloaded jquery with npm as all other plugins I am using. I might be mistaken but I don't think it is the same situation as the other question.

Browserify gulp task (called as a module):

```
var browserify = require('browserify');
var source = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var buffer = require('vinyl-buffer');
var gutil = require('gulp-util');

module.exports = function(gulp, plugins, config) {
  return function() {
    var b = browserify({
      entries: config.srcAssets + '/js/app.js',
      debug: true
    });

    return b.bundle()
      .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
      .pipe(buffer())
      .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init({
        loadMaps: true
      }))
      .on('error', gutil.log)
      .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write('./'))
      .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest + '/js'));
  };
};
```

I simplified my files to the maximum to explain my problem.

app.js :

```
var form = require('./form');
```

form.js :

```
var $ = require('../../../config/node_modules/jquery');
var validator = require('../../../config/node_modules/jquery-validation');
$("#form").validate();
$(function() {
  $('.printArea').height($('#form').height());
})
```

It doesn't work, because the jquery validation plugin will always be above jquery in the bundle.js file. If I don't require the validation plugin and remove the js which depends on it (so only leaving my own jquery manipulations), it works.

Comment: Why would the plugin be above jQuery in the bundle?

Comment: I don't know but I can tell that is the case. Browserify puts it above jquery so the bundle is broken!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [order dependencies: jQuery is not defined with browserify](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334974/order-dependencies-jquery-is-not-defined-with-browserify)

Comment: I edited my question. I don't think it is a duplicate, because I installed jquery with npm, not the case of the other question. Browserify-shim is not the solution here. (also I'm using gulp on top of that, I don't think gulp is the culprit here but it's still different)

Comment: I think `browserify-shim` IS the answer here, at least based on my experience with RequireJS where you use shims to make sure dependencies-of-dependencies are loaded. The issue is specifically with the ordering of dependencies, and shims help manage that order.

Comment: I don't understand why, I loaded all my plugins with npm.. Believe me I googled a lot on this, and everytime it was specified that since the latest jquery versions (that I'm using ofc), there was no need for it anymore. Also using browserify-shim will bloat my js directory with json and modules that I will need to install again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem you're having with `jquery-validation` is that the NPM package is just the source; you still have to build a copy of the distributed file in order to use it, or pull it from Bower or a CDN. It isn't an NPM lib that can be included with Browserify. You will still need some kind of transform to package the *built* copy of `jquery-validation` for use in your app.

Comment: alright I understand. I was on the false assumption that every npm package was able to get browserified. So do you confirm that I need to write another package.json with b-shim etc, specific to my own js files ? (which are away from the gulp/node_modules huge directory)

Comment: Uh, I don't know why a project would have more than one `package.json` so no, I don't think I'm saying that.

Comment: Yeah the issue is that the npm installed jquery-validation package isn't actually a CommonJS module as Browserify would expect it. IMO it shouldn't even be an NPM package as this isn't code that could run in Node or even a commonjs module that Node could load. `jquery-validation`just tries to use '$' from global scope, which is not where browserify puts jQuery after it is loaded with `require()`. You might be able to use browserify-shim to expose jquery as `window.$` but I'm not sure, as I haven't had to do that before.

Comment: yes I had this problem with another plugin aswell. After one day and a half I managed to use browserify-shim the right way. I think the best thing to do would be to only use commonjs modules

Answer (score 0):

Here is how this problem was solved :

in package.json :

```
  "browser": {
    "jquery-validate" :  "./node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "browserify-shim"
    ]
  },
  "browserify-shim": {
    "jquery-validate" :  {
      "depends" :  [
      "jQuery"
      ]
    }
  }
```

in form.js :

```
$ = jQuery = require('../../../config/node_modules/jquery');
require('../../../config/node_modules/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.js');
```