# How to require jQuery in Node using Gulp?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ecmascript-6, use-strict

Building a PWA on top of NodeJS. Utilizing `gulp` to processes `package/bundle` for production. Also using `jQuery`.

Receiving the error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

`package.json`:

```
"devDependencies": {
  "browserify": "^16.2.2",
  "gulp": "^3.9.1",
  "gulp-browserify": "^0.5.1",
  "gulp-clean-css": "^3.10.0",
  "gulp-concat-css": "^3.1.0",
  "gulp-if": "^2.0.2",
  "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.4",
  "gulp-uglify": "^3.0.1",
  "gulp-webserver": "^0.9.1",
  "jquery": "^3.3.1",
  "sw-precache": "^5.2.1"
}
```

Gulp task is:

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
return gulp.src(src + '/js/app.js')
    .pipe(browserify())
    .pipe(gulpif(environment === 'production', uglify()))
    .on('error', function (err) {
        console.error('Error!', err.message);
    })
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + '/js'));
});
```

`app.js` is:

```
(function () {
  'use strict';
  var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');
  require('./bootstrap-3.3.7.min.js');
  $('.loader').fadeOut(1000);

  if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
    navigator.serviceWorker
    .register('./service-worker.js')
    .then(function (registration) 
      console.log('Service Worker Active', registration.scope);
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
      console.log('Service worker registration failed : ', err);
    });
  }
})(); // Page Ready
```

If my understanding of Node is correct, `jQuery` gets included from the `require` call before used the `$`. So I am confused as to why I am receiving the error.

Note that while other posts have had issues with Browserify and jQUery, I do not believe that is the issue.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [order dependencies: jQuery is not defined with browserify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25334974/order-dependencies-jquery-is-not-defined-with-browserify)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `use strict`, which prevents any miss creation of global variable.

Thus when issue is with `var $ = jQuery = require('jquery');` as accidental variable jQuery which doesn't exist is been created as global variable and assigned to `$`. `use strict` prevented this.

Just use

```
'use strict';
 var $ = require('jquery');
```

Also do read [What does 'use strict' do in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851)

Comment: Thanks! That seems to be the issue. I had been playing with that thinking it might be the culprit and I had already tried your suggestion. When I try that, Bootstrap balks saying that it requires jQuery. Do you know of a way to utilize 'use strict', which I like using to protect things, and require jQuery into the code? Perhaps there is a better way to go about this? Let me know if oyu would like to see more code.

Comment: Also, I forgot to ask...I use VS Code and ESLint. Are you aware of a lineter setting that woudl have caught this?

Comment: can also use jshint with your Visual Studio or Sublime or anyother by installing their plugin for jshint

Comment: I used to use JSHint, but I moved to ESLint due to using more ECMAScript features.

Comment: JSHint got lots of add on to file to let them know what to check for or not. like add this to top of js file `/*jshint multistr: true,node: true, esversion: 6, undef: true, unused: true, varstmt: true*/`     for more options see http://jshint.com/docs/options/

Comment: To expose the imported jQuery library to both `$` and `jQuery`, what I've done in the past is just set those variables on to the `window` object after the import:

`var jQuery = require('jquery');
window.$ = window.jQuery = jQuery;`